# react-navigation custom tab component hide label

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I've been working on a custom tab button that shows a 'plus' button in the center of the bottom tab navigator, however, the label text still shows underneath my custom tab button, I tried to remove it  by doing this:

```
const tabBarOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
  tabBarOptions: {
    showLabel: () => {
      const { routeName } = navigation.state
      if (routeName === 'Create') return false
    }
  }
})
```

However, it seems like tabBarOptions does not accept a function that returns an object. Do you guys have any config option available to turn off label for one specific tab component? if it's custom component.
[image]

Comment: Try `showLabel: navigation.state.routeName === 'Create'`

Comment: @bennygenel Thanks, very neat solution, I forgot the fact that I could directly use navigation object in here. If you want to make it an answer I'll gladly accept it.